# In a separate function, find largest value in array and return largest value + array index of largest value in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, function

I've gone through scores of different posts on StackOverflow and several other sites trying to find the answer to my issue without success. Hoping someone can help me with this. I am required to write a function, named findMax, that will find the largest value in an array (values in Main) and return that largest value as well as the array index of the largest value. However, I can't seem to get it to pass.

I am getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'." Yet, when I look up similar scenarios and code, it seems to work fine. In attempting to troubleshoot, I even commented out a few lines. Any help would be appreciated. Code below.

```
using System;
class IT213M4
{
    static int[] arrayOfInt = { 56, 77, 23, 12, 88, 59, 97, 33, 38, 64 }; // array contains 10 int elements initialized with the values "56,77,23,12,88,59,97,33,38,64"
    public int[] findMax()
    {
        int i;
        int max = arrayOfInt[0];
        //int idx = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < arrayOfInt.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arrayOfInt[i] > max)
            {
                max = arrayOfInt[i];
            }
            /*if (arrayOfInt[idx] > max)
            {
                max = arrayOfInt[idx];
            }
            idx++;*/
        }
        return max;
    }
      static void Main()
      {
        // output each array element's value
        foreach (int value in arrayOfInt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{value}");
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: `max` is a single integer, you've stated that `findMax()` returns an `int[]` (an array of integers). You have to return the same type as the method signature declares the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared that your function findMax() returns an array of integer (int[]). But you wrote it to return a single integer variable, max.

Try this:

```
public int[] findMax()
{
    int i;
    int max = arrayOfInt[0];
    //int idx = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < arrayOfInt.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrayOfInt[i] > max)
        {
            max = arrayOfInt[i];
        }
        /*if (arrayOfInt[idx] > max)
        {
            max = arrayOfInt[idx];
        }
        idx++;*/
    }
    return new int[]{max, i};
}
```